# ko is undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'applyBindings' of undefined

I looked in the Network tab in chrome and I see that knockout.js is loaded.
I can type `window.ko` on the Console tab and see knockout's code

So, why the error?

config.js:

```
var require = {
  baseUrl: "/scripts"
};
```

main.js:

```
require([
    "lib/knockout"
],
function (ko) {
    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
    <script data-main="app/main.js" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: test" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Knockout's AMD/RequireJS support depends on the condition [`if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd'])`](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/build/fragments/amd-pre.js). If that and the former test for CommonJS runtimes don't pass, it'll default to defining the global `window.ko`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `ko` parameters from your callback signature.

Comment: You are using the `ko` passed to the callback instead of the intended `window.ko`

Comment: yes, but I often see this done with require() and define(), they match up order in define with order in callback?

Answer (score 2):

You should look for the shim configuration in requirejs and export the ko symbol.